# slash command discord.py name 'create_option' is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a slash command but I'm getting this error.
I'm using Python 3.8.12, discord.py 1.7.3

```
@slash.slash(name="bancmd", description="Banna un utente", guild_ids=guild_ids, options=[
                create_option(
                  name="Utente",
                  description="Seleziona l'utente da bannare",
                  option_type=6,
                  required=True
                ),
                create_option(
                  name="Motivo",
                  description=" ",
                  option_type=3,
                  required=false
                )
             ])
async def bancmd(ctx:SlashContext, Utente: discord.Member, Motivo: str):

    if Motivo==None:
      reason=" ||motivo non specificato|| "
    await Utente.ban(reason = reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(
    description = f'{Utente.mention} è stato bannato per {reason}',
    title = "Ban",
    colour = discord.Color.red()
  )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

error:

```
File "main.py", line 165, in <module>
    create_option(
NameError: name 'create_option' is not defined
```

Please help me

Comment: Please provide your imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following import statement to your code

```
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
```